# Get PNG image file dimension

Tags: visual-c++, png

I would like to get the dimension of a PNG image file inside my local folder on Windows. How can I achieve this using visual c++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be easy, the png file is formed by an 8 byte intro, followed by a header chunk. Inside the header chunk you have the length (4 bytes), type (4 bytes), followed by the width and height.

So basically, the width is the 4 byte number at 8+8=16 bytes in the file, and the height is at 8+8+4=20 bytes in the file. Just read them!

Comment: is there any png c++ library to do this?

Comment: Of course, GDI+ comes to mind. But they decode the entire image and that takes time (and memory). If all you're interested is the size, it's easier to just read it from the file.

Answer (score 0):

aside from the well-known GDI APIs (I get the feeling you are trying to avoid these) it is worth giving http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776499%28v=VS.85%29.aspx a shot. Never used it myself though :/